# Linear programming, Help!

Tags: programming

Can someone please help me.
I have a function

```
f[x_] := 3*(x - Pi/2)*(Sin[4*x])^2 + 2*Cos[3*x]
```

and I need to find coefficients of function

```
g[x_]:= c1 + c2*x + c3*x^2 + c4*x^4
```

so that maximum absolute error of `( Abs[f[x] - g[x]])` is minimized. On the range of `0 <= x <= Pi`.

Please help me, I'm desperate.

Comment: Look up `NonLinearModelFit` in the docs.

Comment: That is for least squared - method, I need to find function so the maximum absolute error is minimized

Comment: `FindFit` has an option called `NormFunction`, I think that is what you are after.

Comment: I don't know, everyone told me I need to solve this by Linear programming (optimzation)

Comment: Could you show me how to solve this problem using Norm Function?

Comment: Might want to check [the Remez method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Both `FindFit` and `NonLinearModelFit` seem to require one to supply data points.  Are you suggesting OP generate data points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I was away from my computer and could not write up an answer right away. I think this is what you want:

Generate some data points that `FindFit` can work with:

```
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/1000}];
```

Use `FindFit` with the infinity norm (see the docs of `NormFunction` for an example):

```
bestfit = FindFit[N@data, g[x], {c1, c2, c3, c4}, x, NormFunction -> (Norm[#1, Infinity] & )]
```

> `{c1 -> 0.880948, c2 -> -8.93938, c3 -> 6.25143, c4 -> -0.385789}`

Notice that it is different when least squares is used:

```
FindFit[N@data, g[x], {c1, c2, c3, c4}, x]
```

> `{c1 -> 1.4222, c2 -> -10.3303, c3 -> 6.92248, c4 -> -0.409044}`

Store the best-fit expression:

```
h = g[x] /. bestfit;
```

Compare:

```
Plot[{f[x], h}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: While it seems somewhat inelegant (and dangerous, if one is not sufficiently careful) to generate data points from an exact function, I don't see another way to do it.  +1